# Google Charts - Change chart x-axis dynamically when bounded to a control

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have 5 columns of data in my DataTable where column 0 and 4 have different x-axis values I would like to plot against and columns 1-3 have the y-axis data to plot.

I have a ChartRangeFilter ControlWrapper bounded to an AreaChart ChartWrapper in a Google Charts Dashboard.

I start off the chart with a view setting the columns to [0,1,2,3] which is working fine, plotting the values against column 0 as the x-axis.

I then have a button to toggle between a view setting the columns to [4,1,2,3] and back to [0,1,2,3] using the following javascript function:

```
function toggleView(){
    if(mode == "byTest"){
        view.setColumns([4,1,2,3]);
        chartWrapper.draw();
        dash.bind([control], [chartWrapper]);
        dash.draw(view);
        mode = "byTime";
    } else {
        view.setColumns([0,1,2,3]);
        chartWrapper.draw();
        dash.bind([control], [chartWrapper]);
        dash.draw(view);
        mode = "byTest";
    }
}
```

The chartWrapper updates to use the new x-axis from column 4 fine, but the controlWrapper loses functionality with the following errors:

> "One or more participants failed to draw()"
>
> "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"
>
> "Undefined is not a function"

When the button toggles back to use the original columns [0,1,2,3] everything works fine again.

[An example of my code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srrrn9sa/70/)

So how do you update the x-axis of a Google Chart dynamically when you have a chart bound to a control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the Dashboard and/or ChartWrapper and ControlWrapper are not prepared to deal with changing data type as much as they should.  Rebuilding the entire Dashboard appears to be required, which I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/srrrn9sa/73/

Using this bit of code:

```
control.clear();
control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: controlOptions
});

chartWrapper.clear();
chartWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'AreaChart', //'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: options
});
dash.clear();
dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
dash.bind([control], [chartWrapper]);
```